# How to integrate client code inside server with swagger and spring boot framework

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I am new to the whole micro-services world, but i am tasked with developing a micro-service. The specifications are created with swagger(now OpenAPI) and the code generated is in spring boot framework.

My specific problem, can be converted to a much more generic one. Assume there are two micro-services. Lets call them "Token service" and "Blacklist Service". The client requests for a token from the "Token service" and the it will check with "Blacklist Service" to know whether the user has been blacklisted or not. If not blacklisted, the client will be given a token; otherwise the request is rejected. I am able to create these two micro-services using swagger and they are running independently fine.

My issue is as follows. Once the client requests for a token, the "Token service" needs to check with "Blacklist Service". The swagger specification generates a client as well as server code to do that. How will I integrate the client code of "Blacklist Service" with the server code of "Token service". I couldn't find any good resources explaining that. My sample yml files are given below.

token.yml

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: Get token
  version: 0.0.1
  title: Token Service
host: 'localhost:8080'
basePath: /test/v1.0
schemes:
  - http
paths:
  /Create:
    get:
      summary: Get token
      parameters:
        - name: payload
          in: body
          description: The person requesting for token
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
              token:
                type: string
        '403':
          description: Forbidden
```

blacklist.yml

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  description: Blacklist Service
  version: 0.0.1
  title: Blacklist Service
host: 'localhost:8081'
basePath: /test/v1.0
schemes:
  - http
paths:
  /blacklist:
    get:
      summary: Check whether the user is blacklisted
      parameters:
        - name: payload
          in: body
          description: The name of user
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              name:
                type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
        '404':
          description: Not found
```

Or is there any way to do this in the yml file itself, to let swagger know that the client code of another service needs to be generated along with server.

It can be argued that the "Blacklist Service" is not required in this case. But my original problem requires checking with another service.
Using OpenAPI 2.0 with Java 8 on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the another micro service by using Rest Template.
please refer this for rest call.

https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-restful/spring-restful-client-resttemplate-example/